# reset the columndefintion in a grid with gridsplitter?

Tags: grid, gridsplitter

i ve got a grid with two columns and a gridsplitter in the middle. So the user can use his own division of the grid. Now i search for a way to reset the Grid to start (both columns are in the same width).

A solution without the Gridsplitter i ve got: the Width-Property of the columns are in styles and these are switchable with a button and a InteractionTrigger. But this way doesn't work when the gridsplitter have been moved.

What do the Gritsplitter exactlly in the grid?

Thanks a lot.